# Not so simple scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know how describe what I have, so I'm just showing the code

```
<div class="room-pos">
<div class="right-content nano-content">
    <div id="right-fix">

    </div>
</div>
    <div class="left-content ">

    </div>
</div>

.room-pos{
    position: relative;
}

.fixed-c{
    position:fixed;
}

.right-content{
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:5;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.left-content{
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#right-fix').height() - $(window).height() + 30) {
        $('#right-fix').addClass( "fixed-c");
        $("#right-fix").css("top", $(window).height() - $('#right-fix').height() );
      } else if($(this).scrollTop() < $('#right-fix').height() - $(window).height() + 30) {
        if ($('#right-fix').hasClass( "fixed-c")){
          $('#right-fix').removeClass( "fixed-c");
        }
      }
```

});

[Same code in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05otmu7a/2/)

**What I want to build**:

So now when you scroll down for some `scrollTop` parameter, the right block becomes `fixed` and `top: - some px` like `top: -832px` . I want to change this so when the right block becomes `fixed`, and after you start scroll to the top of the page, the right block starts scroll to the top too.
So, when you scroll to the bottom, the right block also scrolls to the bottom and becomes `fixed`, and when you scroll to the top the right scrolls to the top, too. So I think I must change `top` in `css` parametr dynamic, something like that

I'm having a hard time explaining what I mean - I hope somebody understands.

**UPDATE:** New link demo!

**UPDATE 2:** Add what I wnat to build but with bugs in algorithm [CODE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/05otmu7a/4/)

Comment: Try to find a site that has the effect you are going for. Providing a link to an example will help others understand.

Comment: I want to find, but I realy don't know what site can do this

Comment: What if `$('#right-fix').height()` was less than `$(window).height()`?  `$(element).css('top', '-'+increment+'px');`

Comment: yes it is necessary to register, but that's not my question, but also thx for that

Comment: @willoller update my question, it's works with bugs but illustrate what I want

Comment: Does this example do what you want? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix